# Material ui Autocomplete press enter to create new chips

Tags: javascript, reactjs, autocomplete, material-ui

I wish I could do such a thing using Autocomplete of material ui: [wertarbyte](https://mui.wertarbyte.com/#chipinput)

That is, inserting text (string) without having a list of elements from which you must select.

Therefore the noOptions message should not appear, every time the enter key is pressed on the keyboard the text is inserted.

[image]

Link: [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-8c31j)

Code:

```
import React from "react";
import Chip from "@material-ui/core/Chip";
import Autocomplete from "@material-ui/lab/Autocomplete";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  root: {
    width: 500,
    "& > * + *": {
      marginTop: theme.spacing(3)
    }
  }
}));

export default function Tags() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <Autocomplete
        multiple
        id="tags-outlined"
        options={[]}
        defaultValue={["foo", "bar"]}
        //getOptionLabel={(option) => option}
        //defaultValue={[top100Films[13]]}
        //filterSelectedOptions
        renderInput={params => (
          <TextField
            {...params}
            variant="outlined"
            label="filterSelectedOptions"
            placeholder="Favorites"
          />
        )}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In case you have simple elements (not objects, just strings), and you don't really need to handle state (your autocomplete is not controlled) you can use the `freeSolo` prop of the `Autocomplete`.

```
<Autocomplete
    multiple
    freeSolo
    id="tags-outlined"
    options={["foo", "bar"]}
    defaultValue={["foo", "bar"]}
    renderInput={params => (
        <TextField
            {...params}
            variant="outlined"
            label="filterSelectedOptions"
            placeholder="Favorites"
        />
    )}
/>
```

In case your elements are more complex and you do need to control the element:

1. Make sure the Autocomplete tag is a controlled one (you manage to value).
2. Listen to key down event on the TextField.
3. If the code is `Enter` (`e.code === 'Enter'`) - take the value of the input and push it to the list of the current values that you have.
4. Make sure you also handle the `onChange` to handle the removal of elements:

Here is the code:

```
const [autoCompleteValue, setAutoCompleteValue] = useState(["foo", "bar"]);

return (
  
  <Autocomplete
    multiple
    id="tags-outlined"
    options={[]}
    value={autoCompleteValue}
    onChange={(e, newval, reason) => {
      setAutoCompleteValue(newval);
    }}
    renderInput={params => (
      <TextField
        {...params}
        variant="outlined"
        label="filterSelectedOptions"
        placeholder="Favorites"
        onKeyDown={e => {
          if (e.code === 'enter' && e.target.value) {
            setAutoCompleteValue(autoCompleteValue.concat(e.target.value));
          }
        }}
      />
    )}
  />
);
```

Check the live working example of both options: https://codesandbox.io/s/mui-autocomplete-create-options-on-enter-gw1jc

Comment: I have seen the example but there are some problems:
1) If I click on the x (delete) of the chip it is not deleted
2) If I click on the x (delete) of the input field, not all the chips are deleted
3) Every time I write a text on the input field, the text 'No option' appears

Comment: @Paul code updated to support two options (controlled / uncontrolled elements)

Comment: Thank you for your help, but there still seem to be problems.
Taking into consideration the first example with the following version: https://codesandbox.io/s/mui-autocomplete-create-options-on-enter-6pbti?file=/demo.js

How can I access the value of the elements contained in Autocomplete?

Comment: You can't. This is exactly the difference between a controlled Autocomplete (where you use the `value`) and a not-controlled Autocomplete (where you use the `defaultValue`). If you move to the controlled one - you can access it (but you will need to manage it).

Comment: Note that you can still use the `onChange` function `onChange={(e, val, reason) => { console.log(val) }}`, but you will need to same the value somewhere in order to access it.

Comment: I think the only solution could be such a thing: https://codesandbox.io/s/mui-autocomplete-create-options-on-enter-lbe6f?file=/demo.js

Although I can't have default values, it's a shame.

Comment: If you save the data just move to a controlled component. I don't really understand the issue. My answer gives you both options - controlled and uncontrolled. Is there still any issue with this answer based on your question?

Comment: So maybe it seems to work, you say: https://codesandbox.io/s/mui-autocomplete-create-options-on-enter-x9e44

Comment: Yes, exactly as in my answer :)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Saved my day but there is a typo on line `"setAutoCompleteValue(autocompleteValue.concat(e.target.value));`  `autocompleteValue` should be `autoCompleteValue`. Cheers

Comment: @SerdarSayın thanks for your comment. I updated the answer and fixed the issue :-)

Comment: instead of e.keyCode === 13 you should use e.code === "Enter"

Comment: @Ar26 thanks for your comment. You are absolutely right!

Answer (score 4):

For anyone who wants to input the **current best match** on enter key press (as opposed to any custom text) you can use the `autoHighlight` prop.

```
<Autocomplete
    multiple
    autoHighlight
    id="tags-outlined"
    options={["foo", "bar"]}
    defaultValue={["foo", "bar"]}
    renderInput={params => (
        <TextField
            {...params}
            variant="outlined"
            label="filterSelectedOptions"
            placeholder="Favorites"
        />
    )}
/>
```

Comment: This sounds like [what I'm trying to do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75071343) but I want to use `Tab` instead of `Enter`. From the `onKeyDown`, can I get the value of the current best match somehow?

Comment: @Sasgorilla You could use `onHighlightChange` to keep the currently highlighted value in a state variable and refer to that in `onKeyDown`. Use `useRef` for that to not re-render the component unnecessarily.

Answer (score 2):

To do this, don't use the `Autocomplete` element from MUI. Just use a a standard `TextField` with the use of `InputProps`. All you need to do is add a `onKeyDown` listener to the `TextField` that listens for 'Enter' and when the function is triggered, have it add to an array of Chips in the `InputProps`. It might look something like this:

```
const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState('');
const [chips, setChips] = useState([])
const inputChange = ({target: {value}}) => {setInputValue(value)};
const handleKeyDown = ({key}) => {
 if(key === 'Enter') {
  setChips([...chips, inputValue])
 }
};
     <TextField
            fullWidth
            variant="outlined"
            label="Fish and Chips"
            value={inputValue}
            onChange={inputChange}
            multiline
            InputProps={{
              startAdornment: chips.map((item) => (
                <Chip
                  key={item}
                  label={item}
                />
              )),
            }}
          />
```

This is untested as written here, but it should work. I've done something similar in one of my apps.

Comment: but you will lose the autocomplete dropdown this way..