# How can I implement tab completion in a MUI Autocomplete?

Tags: material-ui, autocomplete

I'm using a [MUI Autocomplete](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-autocomplete/) component. If the user types a substring that matches only one option, I'd like her to be able to hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> to automatically fill it in. (Which is kinda what I thought "autocomplete" meant ...)

[image: autocomplete with one matching option]

How can I do that?